# Dynamic variable change VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in VB.NET:

```
Dim Hello As String = "123"
temp = Fix_this(hello)
 
Function Fix_this(The_content As String)
    The_content = "456" : Return "test"
End Function
```

I want function `Fix_This` to change the string variable "Hello" without knowing the name of that variable even. I know I can return a new Hello string but I want to return something else.

Is there a way in `Fix_this` function, it can figure out the source of the "The_content" ?

So my goal is `fix_this` function to find out the source of The_content is "Hello" and then being able to dynamically change the Hello value in the function. No idea if I'm making any sense?

So let's say I succeed and I get string value "Hello". How do I then change the hello value? For example:

```
Source_of_The_content =   "Hello"
```

If I do this:

```
Source_of_The_content  = "New"
```

it obviously is not going to change the "Hello" string value to New.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a Function or Sub to modify the parameter it receives, declare the parameter as [`ByRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byref). Using your `Fix_this`function:

```
Function Fix_this(ByRef The_content As String) As String
    The_content = "456"
    Return "test"
End Function
```

If you run the following code, `The_content` will be "456":

```
Dim Hello As String = "123"
MsgBox("Hello before Fix_this: " & Hello)
Dim temp As String = Fix_this(Hello)
MsgBox("Hello after Fix_this: " & Hello)
MsgBox("temp: " & temp)
```

You can also do this by using a Sub if you are just interested in modifying `The_content`:

```
Sub Fix_this(ByRef The_content As String)
    The_content = "456"
End Sub
```

Comment: this is awesome and perfect. Just what I needed. One question though. How can I do this without using function? How can I change a variable without changing it directly by just knowing the name of the variable in vb.net?  Thank you !!!!!

Comment: Take a look at [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname?view=net-6.0). You can create a property for your variable like `Public Property hello As String = "123"` and then update it like this: `CallByName(Me, "hello", CallType.Let, "456")`

Comment: @Maria, why do you think that you need modify a variable based on  name stored as a string? It's very rare that you should need to do that so, if you think you do, it's probably the result of bad design.

Comment: @Maria If you want to be able to access values by name, you should set up the data structure for managing it yourself.  For what you are discussing, I would recommend looking at a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.